# Is there anyway to load a bunch of images from Resources?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hey guys, im getting a little problem here. I am getting a [Level 1 Warning from my debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574835/getting-received-memory-warning-level-1).
So, i think the best solution for it is loading every images of resource, to prevent crash the app like it are doing.

So, whats the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean you are getting a memory warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several strategies to reduce memory usage if you're working with lots of images. The warning you're getting doesn't necessarily mean that main memory is running out, but you could be running low on video ram.

1. Reduce the image size before adding them to your project, both by scaling them down and/or compressing image data.
2. Load only the images you need at a particular time - avoid trying to keep all images in memory.
3. Load images using (UIImage)imageWithContentsOfFile: rather than (UIImage)imageNamed: (the latter reads an caches images immediately, the former is more "lazy").
4. Be aggressive in 'release'ing images - don't wait for autorelease to kick in, but send [image release];
5. Simplify other aspects of your code that use video ram (e.g. remove layer transparency, remove views that aren't currently visible, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs more details I think to get a clear answer.

Anyway, the best solution not to get a memory warning while loading "a bunch of images"... 
is...

Not loading these images! Only load required images "on demand".

For example if you have images in a table view, make cells loads images only when they are visible.

Comment: And release images when they're no longer needed.